# Deadloop after using orderby

Tags: linq

I want to get a list of files in a folder in which the files are named as 0.html, 1.html, 2.html,... 10.html, 11.html.....

I want to sort them by number, not by preceding number.

so I write the query

```
var SeedPages = from pages in Directory.GetFiles(DownloadFolderString) orderby pages.Length select pages;
```

when I access SeedPages.First(), it keeps looping at pages.Length

I don't understand why the program goes back to the query statement.

Comment: "_I want to sort them by number_" What do you call the "number"? What's the value of "DownloadFolderString"? "_it keeps looping at pages.Length_": Error message? We need a little bit more details about the error.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this. `var SeedPages = from pages in Directory.GetFiles("C:\\cygwin") orderby pages.Length select pages; var firstPage = SeedPages.First(); Console.ReadLine();` retrieves the first page and a breakpoint set to the `ReadLine` is hit.

Answer (score 2):

The execution of this **LINQ** statement is deferred, you can put all resulting values in a list or array by calling `.ToList()` or `ToArray()` on your **LINQ** statement.

Comment: This *specific* statement is deferred, not all statements are.

Comment: Agree with @Stijn, moreover calling ToList() or First() on the next line is similar if he doesn't need to perform other operations on the list.

Comment: now I think it probably works out fine. It's just slow.
I have 125 files. The number of looping times is 125x125? It appears to be dead. When I use 3 files, it takes longer than I thought.

Comment: @user1978421 did you put the `.ToList()` right after `select pages`? Then you get a list of that string. You need to put everything in braces: `(from .. select pages).ToList();`